regex first word optional
I'm using regex "/prometheus/(api|config)/v1/(rules(/.*)?|alerts)" to match /prometheus/api/v1/alerts which is working fine. I'm finding it hard to match /api/v1/alerts so that the regex matches for both the usecases

"(/prometheus)?/(api|config)/v1/(rules(/.*)?|alerts)" ?
